# Alternatives for ivyDE

Tags: java, ivy, ivyde

I have huge project that is totally dependent on ivyDE and we are now looking forward to move from it.

Are there any other better options that can replace ivy stuff?

Any advice?

Comment: Are you wanting to replace your dependency management system? or simply the IDE integration for Ivy?

Comment: thekbb - goal is to eventually replace the dependency management system...but for now simplify the IDE integration!

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend switching over to [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) which gives you top notch dependency management capabilities. You've mentioned ivyDE that is Eclipse feature for Ivy, so if you'd decide to use Maven then you can use [Maven Eclipse Plug-In](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) that plays very well.

I'm speaking from my own experience and I've been using Maven in production for big projects (40+ of artifacts) for years with great success.

Comment: Maven 3 is definitely more powerful and feature rich than Ant + Ivy.

Comment: In my opinion Ant + Ivy can be very powerful too. Ant has many long-time users who're never ready go give up Ant's flexibility :) So, these two are slightly different tools, but since @HonorGod has already started looking to move from Ant + Ivy I think Maven is definitely viable option.

Comment: Maven 3 is just a "flexible" as Ant, but 90% or more of what you would have to write yourself in Ant has already be done for you in Maven 3.

Comment: I know Maven and there is no option I would trade that for Ant :) I love Maven stuff! All I'm saying is that Ant has its strengths and I know there are folks who have at lease equal affection to And as I have to Maven. This is somehow discussions similar to classic: VI  vs. EMACS.

Comment: Does the maven eclipse plugin really replace IvyDE though?  When I tried it it seemed to take over some of the build process.  I use IvyDE for dependency fetching and nothing else - it's not involved in building at all.